Создание мягкой ссылки в LInux с возможностью запуска из любой директории
В домашнем каталоге текущего пользователя в .program/bin/ лежит исполняемый файл work. Требуется запустить его без указания этого пути (абсолютного или относительного),из любой директории.
Это нужно сделать при помощи мягкой ссылки на исполняемый файл в /usr/local/bin.Возможно выполнение под суперпользователем.
Я пытался решить задачу,составив конвейер из мягкой ссылки и переменной окружения PATH.
ln -s ~/.program/bin/mycoolprogram ~/bin/mycoolprogram | export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
Я пытаюсь понять,как решить данную задачу одной минимальной командой.

Если вы меняете PATH, то непонятно при чём тут /usr/local/bin тогда

Директория /usr/local/bin как правило есть в $PATH.

Если она уже есть в PATH, то непонятно зачем вы его меняете тогда. Что-то с вашей логикой не так

Конкретно задача «запустить его без указания этого пути» решается банальным export PATH="$HOME/.program/bin:$PATH" без всех этих свистоплясок с ~/bin/ и /usr/local/bin, надобность которых неочевидна

@andreymal, я пытаюсь понять, как применить $PATH к мягким ссылкам.

Если нужна мягкая ссылка, то значит сперва создать мягкую ссылку и потом изменить PATH (или наоборот, порядок действий тут не важен). Зачем сюда приплетать конвейер — тоже непонятно: ни одна их этих команд ничего не вводит и ничего не выводит, соответственно конвейеру тут делать просто нечего

@andreymal , ты имеешь ввиду объединение команд через оператор &&?
ln -s $HOME/.program/bin/work $HOME/.local/bin/work && export PATH="$HOME/.program/bin:$PATH"

Эту задачу можно решить без использования переменных окружения командой:
$ sudo ln -s ~/.program/bin/mycoolprogram /usr/local/bin


Но делать так естественно не надо

"Выполнение под суперпользователем запрещено." и "sudo". Вот это поворот!

И работать оно не будет в половине случаев. На многих программах шаред линковка в соседний каталог

@Stanislav Volodarskiy, как бы Вы решили эту задачу?

Я не могу её решить:  sudo запрещено, а без sudo ничего в /usr/local/bin не изменить.

@Stanislav Volodarskiy, я скорректировал условие задачи.Скажите пожалуйста,существует ли альтернативное решение этой задачи при помощи переменных окружения?
